# IGMPv3 Source Filtering Configuration

Tags: netstat, multicast

I know that multicast addresses are being kept in `/proc/net/igmp`. Where is the configuration for v3 source filter being kept? Please note that I do not wish to inspect actual IGMP packets, I wish to see the configured value even if it's not a valid multicast source.

Comment: will this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25872/how-can-i-know-if-ip-multicast-is-enabled

Comment: The answers in that thread do not seem to give source filtering data, but thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can find **IGMPv3** current kernel state in `/proc/net/mcfilter`.

Here is how looks like one group address allowed from 4 sources:

```
# cat /proc/net/mcfilter
Idx Device        MCA        SRC    INC    EXC
8333 bond1. 0xe8ff3329 0xac10f9ce      1      0
8333 bond1. 0xe8ff3329 0xac10f9d6      1      0
8333 bond1. 0xe8ff3329 0xac10f92e      1      0
8333 bond1. 0xe8ff3329 0xac10f936      1      0
```

- `Idx` and `Device` is interface id and name.
- `MCA` - multicast address.

And appropriate igmp request in **tcpdump**:

```
igmp v3 report, 1 group record(s) [gaddr 232.255.51.41 allow { 172.16.249.206 172.16.249.214 172.16.249.46 172.16.249.54 }]
```